# 'System.InvalidCastException' when reading in from database, not a problem for a different field? (React)

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, controller

This is a React app with the Asp.net. The issue concerns a C# controller and a SQL database.

So I have a file that reads in a bunch of info from a database into a controller. Right now, only uses a few fields, which I will specify. The issue is, I have two fields I'm reading in that are ints. One works totally fine, and I've been using it in my UI and my component functionality. The other is giving me a 'System.InvalidCastException' from System.Data.Common.dll, which is causing an 'Unexpected end of JSON Input' error on my webpage. I double checked the SQL tables, and both are stored the same way: int, not null. There are no typos in the name of the fields or anything. Why is it giving me this error for one integer and not the other?

So here is the controller, where I'm reading in the data:

```
var myReturn = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(t => new McProcessInfo()
{
    Application = t.Field<string>("Application"),
    ApplicationID = t.Field<int>("ApplicationId"), //error here
    ApplicationVersion = t.Field<string>("ApplicationVersion"),
    ErrorLevel = t.Field<int>("ErrorLevel"), //no error here
    ErrorMessage = t.Field<string>("ExceptionErrorMessage"), 
    StackTrace = t.Field<string>("StackTrace")
}).ToArray();
return myReturn;
```

And here is the cs file that sets the properties:

```
public class McProcessInfo
{
  public string Application { get; set; }
  public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
  public string ApplicationVersion { get; set; }
  public int ErrorLevel { get; set; }
  public string ErrorMessage {  get; set; }
  public string StackTrace { get; set; }
}
```

I'm hoping that you all can see something I can't. Let me know if you need more information or code.

I commented out every line except for that one, and that's the one that's broken. I haven't tried much of anything because I'm kind of new to this and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Did you check if some row contains a value that is not convertible to an int? With the debugger you could check the DataTable before applying the AsEnumerable

Comment: Is ApplicationId NULL perhaps?

Comment: @VDWWD You were right, it was null, even though that shouldn't be allowed in the SQL. You just saved me hours of debugging, thank you.